Loki, Promtail, S3, ServiceAccount
I installed the Loki Stack on an EKS environment using Helm. It’s a single cluster with two worker nodes. A Loki StatefulSet and two Promtail pods are running.
I created a Service Account and connected S3 with Loki to send chunk data to S3. However, the data is not being sent to S3.
I reduced the chunk size, but the changes are not being applied. I even tried editing the Secret directly, but the data is still not going to S3.
Below is the Helm values.yaml file.
deploymentMode: SingleBinary
loki:
  image:
    repository: grafana/loki
    tag: 2.9.0
  commonConfig:
    replication_factor: 1
  schemaConfig:
    configs:
    - from: "2024-01-01"
      store: tsdb
      index:
        prefix: loki_index_
        period: 24h
      object_store: s3
      schema: v13
  storage:
    type: 's3'
    bucketNames:
      chunks: <my-s3-bucket-name>/chunks
      ruler: <my-s3-bucket-name>/ruler
      admin: <my-s3-bucket-name>/admin
    s3:
      endpoint: s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
      region: ap-northeast-2
      s3ForcePathStyle: false
      insecure: false
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name: loki-sa
    annotations:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::<my-aws-account>:role/<my-loki-role>"
      
singleBinary:
  replicas: 1
read:
  replicas: 0
backend:
  replicas: 0
write:
  replicas: 0

ingester:
  chunk_block_size: 6000


k exec -it -n loki loki-0 -- ls -larth /data/loki
total 16K
drwxrwsrwx    3 root     loki          18 Oct 14 07:15 ..
drwxr-sr-x    7 loki     loki         120 Oct 14 07:15 .
drwxr-sr-x    4 loki     loki          41 Oct 14 07:20 boltdb-shipper-active
drwxr-sr-x    3 loki     loki          25 Oct 14 07:44 boltdb-shipper-cache
drwxr-sr-x    2 loki     loki           6 Oct 14 08:35 boltdb-shipper-compactor
drwxr-sr-x    3 loki     loki       12.0K Oct 14 08:45 chunks
drwxr-sr-x    3 loki     loki          47 Oct 14 08:45 wal

nothing special in logs of loki-0 pod
k logs -n loki loki-0

